# Algorithms and Pseudocode

Tags: algorithms

The following function written in pseudocode accepts **INCOME** as a variable and outputs the **TAX** corresponding to that income.

**FUNCTION** TAX (INCOME)

1. **IF** (INCOME ≥ 60000) **THEN**

   a. TAXDUE ← 15000
2. **ELSE**

   a. **IF** (INCOME ≥ 30000) **THEN**

   1. TAXDUE ← 5000

   b. **ELSE**

   1. TAXDUE ← INCOME x 0.08
3. **RETURN** (TAXDUE)

What would be the pseudocode output with an input of:

a) 23000?

b) 64000?

c) 47000?

---

Here are my answers:

a) 1840

b) 15000

c) 5000

Am I doing this right, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should be suspicious of your answer if the tax due is equal to the income. While such cases supposedly did occur in Sweden in the 1970s, I don't think that is the case with the simple tax code here.

Comment: I've edited that one.

Comment: what happens if INCOME is negative?

Comment: @ Jon Mark Perry: I'm not sure. Honestly, I'm just trying to get my head around the concept of pseudocode and algorithms. This was a question that was posited as written above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) INCOME=$23000$ fails **IF1**, passes to **ELSEIF2a**, fails so passes to **ELSEIFb** and stores $23000\times0.08=1840$ in TAXDUE in step **2b1**. Control passes to the RETURN statement.

b) INCOME=$64000$ passes **IF1**, and stores $15000$ in TAXDUE in step **1**. Control passes to the RETURN statement.

c) INCOME=$47000$ fails **IF1**, passes to **ELSEIF2a**, passes and stores $5000$ in TAXDUE in step **2a1**. Control passes to the RETURN statement.

So you are correct. The pseudocode is a bit weak in it's nesting principles and flow control, but as you didn't write it...:)